# Discord bot just show discord version

Tags: c#, bots, discord, discord.net

I have programmed a discord bot and try to connect to my server. But as I try to connect, I just got the Discord version Discord.Net v2.1.1 (API v6) shown and the program is stuck on the line `await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, bot_token);` forever.
Here is the complete code:

```cs
    public class discord
    {
        private const string bot_token = "<token>";

        public delegate void getMessage(string message);
        public event getMessage ongetmessage;

        private DiscordSocketClient _client;

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig() { LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose });
            _client.Log += Log;
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, bot_token);
            await _client.StartAsync();

            // Block this task until the program is closed.
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
        {
            ongetmessage(msg.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void connect()
        {
            MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
```

And here is the code from the form:

```cs
    private void Discord_ongetmessage(string message)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(Discord_ongetmessage), new object[] { message }); 
            return;
        } 
        this.richTextBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now + ": " + message + "\n");
    }

    private void btn_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        discord.connect();
    }
```

I am using nuget package Discord.net v2.1.1 and Discord.net.core v2.1.1.

Comment: Try wrapping your call to `connect()` in `Task.Run()` --- `_ = Task.Run( () => discord.connect());`

Comment: Wow, still no answer? Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Just making sure, "<token>" is replaced with your actual token, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have either incorrectly created the bot at the [Discord Dev Site](https://discordapp.com/developers), mistyped the token, or perhaps even not invited the bot to your discord server (although I doubt that would cause an await hold).

Also, as @Anu6is said in the comments:

> Try wrapping your call to `connect()` in `Task.Run()` --- `_ = Task.Run( () => discord.connect());`

Hope this helps!